# MySQL oomkiller crashes after backup

Tags: mysql, replication, backup, percona

I am using percona and the backups run successfully. However after the backup is done and sometimes during the backup MySQL is crashing and I am not certain where to start.

Running show engine performance_schema.memory `performance_schema.memory   169474536`
running `free -g`

```
       total        used  free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:   125          58     0           0          66          66
Swap:    9           0     9
```

running `dmesg`

```
Out of memory: Kill process 11779 (mysqld) score 225 or sacrifice child
Killed process 11779 (mysqld) total-vm:36902412kB, anon-rss:31731108kB, file-rss:0kB
```

The backup script is pretty generic

```
dest="current_backup/";
xtrabackup --backup --target-dir=$dest --no-timestamp 2> $log;
xtrabackup --prepare --target-dir=$dest 2>> $log;
```

I am running two instances of MySql on the same server.  But I have a ton of memory and a lot of disk space.
my.cnf

```
sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,E RROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_E NGINE_SUBSTITUTION
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 25G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 8
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 3600000
wait_timeout = 86400
interactive_timeout = 86400
max_heap_table_size = 96M
sort_buffer_size = 16M
join_buffer_size = 16M
tmp_table_size = 96M
max_sort_length = 8K
max_allowed_packet = 16M
group_concat_max_len = 16M
max_connections = 200
max_connect_errors = 10
expire_logs_days = 2
max_binlog_size = 128M

symbolic-links=0
log-bin=binlog
binlog-format=ROW
log_slave_updates
wsrep_log_conflicts
expire_logs_days=7
```

Comment: How much RAM do you have?  Do both instances have the same settings?  Is anything other than MySQL running?

Comment: Doing `free -m ` `Mem:  total = 128834      used =  60369  free = 633  shared = 17 buff/cache = 67832 available = 67562`
`Swap:   total = 9536 used = 523 free = 9013`. Thanks for any advice

Comment: Nothing else is running on the server and both instances have the same setup.